# Post-Doc in Germany

Tags: phd, postdocs, germany, political-science

I am a newbie and have a question. First of all let me introduce myself and the situation in which I am going through.

I have just got my PhD from the Middle East Technical University (Turkey) from the department Political Science. I was also a research assistant between 2011-2018 during my master and doctorate studies. Actually, living outside Turkey had never been one of my plans, but love changes everything. :) I got married with a German citizen and I am living since 6 months in Germany with my wife. During this time, I worked on a few improvements of my PhD Thesis, finally I defended it in December and have got my degree.

So, before I met my wife, my academic plan had been to continue in the Turkish Academia, however, having decided to marry with her, there had been a decision to make: Staying in Turkey (and waiting her to come to Turkey) vs. going to Germany

Considering the last political and economic instability of Turkey, moving to Germany was surely the clever decision to make. Yet, it was so sudden that I couldn't make any academic preparation in 2 years, since I was writting at the same time my PhD thesis. So my migration to Germany was a bit an unplanned one, considering the Academic world, considering especially the fact that in Turkey PhD's are most generally 6 years long. So, I couldn't waste my previous 4 years.

As a result, I want an advise for my further step in Germany, probably post-doc. Actually, I was also born in Germany and lived 8 years here in my childhood, which means that German was once my mother-language however, I couldn't keep it fluent in 25 years. Yet it is still enough to cope with daily issues and conversations, it keeps improving, I am far away than 6 months before, but it is surely not enough for Academy yet.

What do you think? Is post-doc a clever idea in my situation? If so, what are my chances? I do not have English publications yet, but 5 Turkish ones. Moreover, as an additional information, my research topic has been an attention getting one in the German social science circles. Is it possible to apply to a post-doc with a project aiming for international publications based on my PhD thesis, such as articles or a book? Or do I need to write a new research proposal to apply?

Or would you suggest to skip the post-doc and apply to a position as lecturer (which in my opinion seems not possible to end up with a positive result considering my current state)

Or, finally, would you suggest me to postpone my plans on academy, find another work until I make an international publication?

Sorry, for the very long question. 
I will appreciate any of your answers and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia.SE! This is not a forum for recommendations and discussions, but rather a Q&A site. You need to formulate a clear question  as explained in help centre: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

You have publications, even if only in Turkish, on a subject of current interest. I do not if the number of publications is big or small, or anything about the quality. Presumably you know enough German and English to get by, and will pick up German fast.

Based on this information only, apply for all places where you might have a chance of being accepted. To improve your chances, consider if there are people who are

1. famous in your field in Germany, or at least have some name recognition
2. can read Turkish
3. familiar with your work or willing to get familiar, or at least the journals.

If you can find such a person, ask if they can certify that you have published reasonable papers in reasonable journals.

In your application, be honest about your language skills and potential. If a position asks you to immediately teach in German, you might not be the ideal candidate, but if there is a year to learn to language or something similar, you should be qualified.

In the academic world, it is best to apply early and often; getting a position or funding is partially a matter of luck, so making many attempts pays off.

Answer (score 0):

A postdoc is probably the easiest point of entry (instead of lecturer or "real job").  That said, you seem pretty flexible so I would just apply for everything in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is in turkey, but working in germany as a scientist is not so easy. the universities or institutions often don't have enough money to financiate their staff.

maybe you should apply to a daad stipenium. There are programs only for foreign people.  http://www.research-in-germany.org/en/jobs-and-careers/info-for-postdocs-and-junior-researchers.html

In any case the biggest problem for a research institute will be the money to pay you. So if you bring your project or stipendium, the start will be much easier.